# is there a function combin NSSet and FetchResult<>

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

I am coding in Coredata , There are two entity(Message and Keyword) with an one to many relationship. 
first , I creat three Keyword instance using @Environment(.managedObjectContext)  var moc. 
sec, I creat one Message instance using @Environment(.managedObjectContext)  var moc
third, I want add three Keywords into the message but faild, the keywords in message is NSSet,
the message is FetchResults, how it can work, Ths.

```
extension Message {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Message> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Message>(entityName: "Message")
    }

    @NSManaged public var id: UUID?
    @NSManaged public var content: String?
    @NSManaged public var creatAt: Date?
    @NSManaged public var user: User?
    @NSManaged public var keywords: NSSet?
    @NSManaged public var photoes: NSSet?
}
extension Keyword {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Keyword> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Keyword>(entityName: "Keyword")
    }

    @NSManaged public var id: UUID?
    @NSManaged public var title: String?
    @NSManaged public var message: Message?

}
 .navigationBarTitle("Send Message", displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {

            }) {
                Text("Send")
                    .onTapGesture {
                        let newMessage = Message(context: self.moc)
                        newMessage.keywords = self.keywords
            })
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Message class should have a generated method named addToKeywords that takes a Set as an argument

```
newMessage.addToKeywords(self.keywords)
```

Comment: ths,but addToKeywords( value: NSSet) must be NSSet, but my keywords is NSFetcheResults<Keyword> come from moc

Comment: The fetch request returns an array and you can easily create a Set object from an array

Comment: I use this:  newMessage.addToKeywords(NSSet(array: self.KeywordTitleArray)). but in  simulator , the app crash